# How can I remove the baseline from pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.6, baseline

I have a dataframe that, after applying a butter bandpass, looks as follows:
[image]

So far I have tried using

```
newdataframe = signal.detrend(df)
```

However, this changes the format from a data frame to an array.  Is there a way of removing the baseleine from a pandas DataFrame and keep it in this format?

Answer (score 0):

Assign the values back to the dataframe:

```
df.loc[:] = signal.detrend(df)
```